# Question regarding a lemma in Principles of Algebraic Geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, hodge-theory

My question is regarding the lemma on page 81 of the book by Griffiths and Harris.

The lemma says the following:
A $\bar{\partial}$-closed form $\psi\in Z^{p,q}_{\bar{\partial}}(M)$ is of minimal norm in $\psi + \bar{\partial} A^{p,q-1}(M)$ iff $\bar{\partial}^* \psi = 0 $.

Now in the first direction of the equivalence they take $\eta \in A^{p,q-1}(M)$ s.t $\bar{\partial} \eta = 0$; and then they calculate $\| \psi + \bar{\partial}\eta \|^2$; somewhere along the calculations they get because that $\bar{\partial}^* \psi = 0$ that $$\| \psi + \bar{\partial} \eta \|^2 = \| \psi \|^2 + \| \bar{\partial}\eta\|^2 > \|\psi \|^2$$

But obviously if $\bar{\partial} \eta = 0$ then also $\| \bar{\partial} \eta \|^2 = 0 $; Am I missing something here?

I am asking here and not in MSE since its an advanced graduate book, I have slim chances of getting answers over there.

Comment: Yeah, this is a typo in the book, just remove the words "with $\overline{\partial}\eta=0$" from the text, and the argument works.

Comment: I can assure you this question would have received an answer on MSE.

Comment: perhaps change the condition "with ∂¯¯¯η=0" , to "with ∂¯¯¯η ≠ 0"?

Comment: @roy smith: right, since they put a strict inequality